# How to parse QueryString

Tags: go

I have a string such as `username=Test1234&currency=THB` and I need to get value of username or currency

```
qry, _ := url.Parse(string(qryString))
```

Comment: I see you found the net/url package.  Did you try [url.ParseQuery](https://godoc.org/net/url#ParseQuery)?  Did you encounter problems with it?

Answer (score 3):

An example is as follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    address := "http://example.com?name=poloxue&age=11"

    u, err := url.Parse(address)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(u.RawQuery)

    q, err := url.ParseQuery(u.RawQuery)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(q.Get("name"))
}
```

Output:

```
name=poloxue&age=11
poloxue
```

Comment: `URL` has `Query()` which calls `ParseQuery` on its own `RawQuery` for you.

Comment: @hobbs After reading the source code, `Query` doesn't return error.

Comment: True enough, but an error from `ParseQuery` is also not fatal — it returns everything it could parse even if there was an error (including pairs *after* the error). `Query` does the same, and just doesn't tell you about the error.